# Using a PHP location header

Tags: php

I am trying to use a variable in a PHP location header, but I can't seem to get it to work. What am I doing wrong?
My Code:

```
$id= 14;

header('Location:collection.php?idollection=$id);
```

Comment: read about variable interpolation

Comment: Variables don't interpolate in single quoted strings. Also strings should be enclosed by two quotes.

Comment: It's not a "php location header", it's http location header

Comment: Simplify your problem: the `header()` function takes a string. You want to create a string with the value of `$id` built into it. Look up the documentation on [string variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score 1):

Just by assumptions.. You want to re-direct with a `$_GET` value based on a variable source?

How about:

```
$id = 1;
header("Location: collection.php?idollection=".$id);
exit;
```

Use of the `exit` will make sure the page will not continue executing after `header` has been called. Furthermore, make sure that there is no whitespaces or any output prior to the header being called.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use double quotes.  You used single quotes and actually only used one.  Try this:

```
header("location:collection.php?idcollection=$id");
```